# Magento remove attribute from attribute set

Tags: attributes, ce-1.9.0.1

How to remove an atribute from an attribute set? All the answers I can find online describe doing it programmatically, I prefer not to

Comment: Did you get any answer on this or were you able to do so. If yes then do share here

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the attribute set in the backend `Catalog->Attributes->Manage attribute set`. And just drag and drop the attribute in the left area.

Comment: It is not allowing it to do so

Answer (score 1):

You have to drag it to the top of the list on the right. Not just into the box for some reason. If you have other Unassigned Attributes drag it in between a couple and you will notice the cursor change.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you've found an answer to this. I had the same problem and was able to find a work around.

**PROBLEM:**

I'm working with `Magento 2 ver 2.1.7` and it seems that once you create a configurable product, any subsequent product you try to add to the catalog is given the same attributes from the product you previously added.

**WHY THIS HAPPENS:**

Under `PRODUCT >> CATALOG >> ADD NEW PRODUCT` the second line in the under Product Details is **Attribute Set** and has automatically selected **default**. So if you make changes for one product, then all products you make thereafter receive those same changes.

**SOLUTION:**

To combat this, you'll want to go to the admin panel on the left-hand side of the screen. Locate `STORES >> ATTRIBUTE SET >> ADD NEW ATTRIBUTE SET`

Under **Groups**, click **ADD NEW**. Name the group & then move whatever attribute you didn't want to the group you just made. Click **DELETE SELECTED GROUP** to remove the attribute. Then click **SAVE**.

e.g. I named my group **test** and the attribute I was removing was **vac_power** I collapsed the tree view and moved and dragged **vac_power** to **test**. Then I deleted the group **test** and saved.

You should now be able to go back to your **PRODUCT CATALOG** and select the new **attribute set** you made in the product details dropdown.

Comment: Wasn't able to delete the group containing that attribute...

Answer (score 0):

You can drag and drop the attribute you want to remove from an attribute set, onto the list on the right called "Unassigned Attributes".  Once you can drop the attribute you'll see the cursor change.

Comment: It is not allowing it to do so